# Responsive.css logo

Tags: wordpress, responsive

my logo is not responsive on mobile phones.

Code below. Wordpress theme: xclean.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you.

```css
/*=============================================
    =            Mobail Menu Style            =
    =============================================*/
  .header-search {
    right: 0;
  }
  .header-search .searchform input[type="text"] {
    width: 160px !important;
  }
  .header-search .searchform input[type="submit"] {
    width: 35px !important;
  }
  .header .site-logo a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center; 
  }
  .header .site-logo .slideItWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .header-cart:hover .dropdown {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .header-cart .dropdown {
    display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Relative units of measure:

```
.header .site-logo a {
    width: 10vw;
}
```

Comment: Link to website: https://vemavm.com/test/ 

There is one more section where "logo" is mentioned, is it probably there somewhere? 

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  /*=======================================
 =            Home Page Style            =
 =======================================*/
    }
  .header .site-logo img {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
    }
  header .site-logo img {
    margin-left: 25px;

Comment: this one worked but it is now shifted to the top left corner: 

}
  .header .site-logo a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
 width: 18vw;
  } 

How can I center it ?

Comment: Fixed it. Found a solution. Had to add an additional line of "margin". Thank you anyways.